# Does aliasing work with function calling in ng-disabled?

Tags: angularjs

First, have a look at my current code:

```
$scope.disableParticipant = function (memberObj) {
        if($scope.memberObj.membertype==1){
            return true;
        } else if($scope.memberObj.membertype==2 && $scope.program.updatePermission){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    };
```

```html
<table>
    <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="memberObj in members | orderBy : ['membername'] as resultMem track by memberObj.id">
        <td align="middle" title="Add/Remove Participant" class="width40">
            <input type="checkbox" ng-disabled="disableParticipant(memberObj)">
        </td>
        <td>
            <$ memberObj.membername $>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" ng-disabled="(disableParticipant(memberObj) && (program.created_by == memberObj.id))">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" ng-disabled="(disableParticipant(memberObj) && (program.created_by == memberObj.id))">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" ng-disabled="(disableParticipant(memberObj) && (program.created_by == memberObj.id))">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" ng-disabled="(disableParticipant(memberObj) && (program.created_by == memberObj.id))">
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here I have used 'disableParticipant' function many times. I am searching any way where I do not need to use the function again & again. I supposed that aliasing with the very first use of function should work but it is not working.

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-disabled="disableParticipant(memberObj) as isDisabled">
```

& I want it to work like

```
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" ng-disabled="isDisabled && (program.created_by == memberObj.id))">
    </td>
```

It didn't work but if there is any other way around, let me know...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [ngInit](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit) to assign result of your function to a variable.

```
<table>
    <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="memberObj in members | orderBy : ['membername'] as resultMem track by memberObj.id" 
        ng-init="isDisabled = (disableParticipant(memberObj) && (program.created_by == memberObj.id))">
        <td align="middle" title="Add/Remove Participant" class="width40">
            <input type="checkbox" ng-disabled="disableParticipant(memberObj)">
        </td>
        <td>
            <$ memberObj.membername $>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" ng-disabled="isDisabled">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" ng-disabled="isDisabled">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" ng-disabled="isDisabled">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" ng-disabled="isDisabled">
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This will not be reactive, i.e. if the condition would change the checkboxes won't change their state.

Comment: You are right. If the author of the question needs it to be reactive he should consider the solution you proposed.

Answer (score 2):

Call this function just after you load your `members` array

```
function updateMembersDisability()
{
   $scope.members.forEach(function(member){
       member.isDisabled = false;
       if(member.membertype==1){
            member.isDisabled = true;
        } else if(member.membertype==2 && $scope.program.updatePermission){
            member.isDisabled = true;
        }
   });
}
```

And then you can use `IsDisabled` property directly like this

```
 <td>
        <input type="checkbox" ng-disabled="memberObj.isDisabled && (program.created_by == memberObj.id))">
    </td>
```

Comment: This will not be reactive, i.e. if the condition would change the checkboxes won't change their state.

Comment: @fracz - So you mean if I change `member.isDisabled` property in the controller it will not have affect? Any reasons?

Comment: If the *condition* change. So, e.g. if you change the `member.membertype` or `$scope.program.updatePermission` it will not be reflected automatically in the `member.isDisabled` field you have introduced. Of course, it depends on whether they will be changed or not - OP does not tell us anything about it.

Comment: BTW - you have `false` three times in your code and no `true`s :-)

Comment: @fracz - Ah! I got your point! You are right! And I corrected that returning `false` thing :)

Answer (score 0):

Aliasing with the `as` keyword is for [controllers](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController) *only*.

You can, however, generate these checkboxes with `ng-repeat` to have a less boilerplate.

```
<tr ng-repeat="memberObj in members | orderBy : ['membername'] as resultMem track by memberObj.id">
    <td align="middle" title="Add/Remove Participant" class="width40">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-disabled="disableParticipant(memberObj)">
    </td>
    <td>
        <$ memberObj.membername $>
    </td>
    <td ng-repeat="i in [1,2,3,4]">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-disabled="disableParticipant(memberObj) && (program.created_by == memberObj.id)">
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a property in your member object once they are loaded like this,

```
function updateMembersDisability()
{
    $scope.members.forEach(function(member){
             Object.defineProperty(member, 'isDisabled', {
             get: function() { 
                    if($scope.memberObj.membertype==1){
                         return true;
                    } else if($scope.memberObj.membertype==2 && $scope.program.updatePermission){
                          return true;
                    }
                     return false;
                 }
            });
       });
}
```